# Expected number of trials of pairs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, expected-value

I've been confused with this question for awhile:

**Suppose there are $n$ balls in a bag and $n$ is even; $3$ are red and $n-3$ are black. At each trial, $2$ balls are taken from the bag without replacement. What is the expected number of trials until a pair with exactly $1$ red ball and $1$ black ball is taken from the bag?**

I've tried different sums like $\sum_{n=1}^{\frac{x}{2}}\frac{x-3}{x-1}\cdot n$, which I thought might work because it uses the probability of a red ball being paired with a black ball, but I realized it doesn't account for the changing probability, since the balls aren't replaced. When I tried to account for these changes by subtracting 2 after the balls are taken out, the expected number still didn't come out correct.

Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated, I've just been so stuck and can't come up with a good probability to work with this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=2m$ and for $k=1,2,\dots,m$ let $A_k$ denote the event that at the $k$-th draw for the first time a red and black ball are drawn.

Then:$$P\left(A_{k}\right)=\frac{2\left[\binom{2m-2k}{2}+k-1\right]}{\binom{2m}{3}}$$
Here the denominator equals the number of ways that we can place the $3$ red balls in a row of $2m=n$ balls.

Thinking from left to right the numerator is the number of ways of placing $3$ red balls in this row such that event $A_k$ occurs.

Then for the expectation we find:$$\sum_{k=1}^mkP(A_k)=$$$$\binom{2m}3^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^m2k\left[\binom{2m-2k}{2}+k-1\right]=\frac{\left(m+1\right)^{2}}{2\left(2m-1\right)}=\frac{\left(n+2\right)^{2}}{8\left(n-1\right)}$$
Not a nice job to work this summation out but it can be done.

---

It would not surprise me if someone provides a more elegant solution.

Comment: If $4$ balls are randomly arranged in a row, instead of counting them as two possible pairs, shouldn't we count them as three possible pairs, viz. 1-2, 2-3, and 3-4 ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Suppose that $n=10$ and pair $(5,6)$ contains a red and black. Then $A_3$ occurs in two situations. 1) both other red balls are among $7,8,9,10$. There are $\binom{2m-2k}{2}=\binom42$ possibilities. 2) one of the pairs $(1,2),(3,4)$ contains both other red balls. There are $k-1=2$ possibilities. In situation 2 I must not take $(2,3)$ as a possibility for containing the two other red balls because in that case $A_1$ occurs (so not $A_3$).

Comment: Thanks, I get it. I have added a warning while I search leisurely for the elusive "elegant" answer which may not exist !

Comment: Disheartened at Nadal's loss, went back to the question at last !

Comment: @trueblueanil Cheer up! He is young enough to come back again. Then as a father.

Comment: I was backing him for most slam titles but he is so injury prone, I think Djokovic may overtake him before both are swamped by the next gen.

Answer (score 1):

- Let $n = 2m$, so  $m$ **boxes** with $2$ balls each, totalling $3$ red and $2m-3$ black
- The red balls can either be $1-1-1$ in $3$ separate boxes or $2-1$ in two boxes
- Placing the $1-1-1$ pattern, the first red ball can go anywhere, the second and third must go in different boxes, thus $Pr = \large\frac{2m-2}{2m-1}\cdot\frac{2m-4}{2m-2} = \frac{2m-4}{2m-1}$, and the other pattern's *Pr* would be the complement $= \frac3{2m-1}$
- In the $1-1-1$ pattern, the three red balls can be considered as separators that, on an average, divide the boxes into four equal parts, thus the first "good" box is [expected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343022/in-n-choose-k-how-many-would-you-first-skip-over-on-average/2343234#2343234) to  be seen **after** $\large\frac{m-3}{4}\;$ boxes, **at** box $\large\frac{m+1}4$
- Similarly, in the $2-1$ case, the first good box is expected at  $\large\frac{m+1}2$,
- Thus the overall expected value weighted by probabilities will be $\left(\Large\frac{2m-4}{2m-1}\cdot\frac{m+1}4\right) +\left(\Large \frac3{2m-1}\cdot \frac{m+1}2\right) = \Large\frac{(m+1)^2}{4m-2}= \frac{(n+2)^2}{8(n-1)}$

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this is the solution for the case of drawing balls with replacement, right? The OP asked for the case of drawing balls without replacement.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch: Thanks for pointing out. I am quite distracted whenever a tennis grand slam is on, alas ! $\;\;$ :)

Comment: Has indeed more elegance than my solution. Glad to see that this time the outcomes are the same.

Comment: @drhab: Thanks for your kind comments !

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios to consider:

1. The first red ball is drawn out at the same time as a black ball.
2. Two red balls are drawn together, then later the third red ball is drawn together with a black ball.

The probability of #1 occurring on the $k$th trial is the probability that we draw $k - 1$ pairs of black balls, followed by one black and one red ball.

The probability of #2 is a bit trickier, but you can look at the probability that it happens on the $j$th trial conditional on the pair of red balls being drawn in the $k$th draw, with the latter event being related to the probability of #1.

Then you just need to collapse all of that down to get the probability that the red-black pair is drawn on the $k$th draw, and then use that to get an expectation.